# Move and transform data between databases using Airflow

Tags: airflow

Using airflow, I extract data from a MySQL database, transform it with python and load it into a Redshift cluster.

Currently I use 3 airflow tasks : they pass the data by writing CSV on local disk.

How could I do this without writing to disk ?
Should I write one big task in python ? ( That would lower visibility )

Edit: this is a question about Airflow, and best practice for choosing the granularity of tasks and how to pass data between them.
It is not a general question about data migration or ETL. In this question ETL is only used as an exemple of workload for airflow tasks.

Comment: I am doing the same thing as you. Did you find a better solution? I read a query with pandas --> process --> save to stringio --> copy_expert

Comment: @trench have you found a better solution?

Answer (score 4):

There are different ways you can achieve this:

If you are using AWS RDS service for MySQL, you can use AWS Data Pipeline to transfer data from MySQL to Redshift. They have inbuilt template in AWS Data Pipeline to do that. You can even schedule the incremental data transfer from MySQL to Redshift

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-redshift.html

How large is your table?
If your table is not too large and you can read the whole table into python using Pandas DataFrame or tuples and then transfer it Redshift.
Even if you have large table still you can read that table in chunks and push each chunk to Redshift.
Pandas are little inefficient in terms of memory usage if you read table into it.

Creating different tasks in Airflow will not help much. Either you can create a single function and call that function in dag using PythonOperator or create a python script and execute it using BashOperator in dag

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is using the GenericTransfer operator from airflow. See [docs](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/_modules/generic_transfer.html#GenericTransfer)

This only works with smallish datasets and the mysqlhook of airflow uses MySQLdb which does not support python 3.

Otherwise, I dont think there are other options, when using airflow, than writing to disk.

Answer (score 2):

How large is your database?

Your approach of writing CSV on a local disk is optimal with a small database, so if this is the case you can write a Python task for that.

As the database get larger there will be more COPY commands and error prone uploading because you’re dealing with billions of rows of data spread across multiple MySQL tables.

You will also have to figure out exactly in which CSV file something went wrong.

It is also important to determine whether you need high throughput, high latency or frequent schema changes.

In conclusion, you should consider a third-party option like Alooma to [extract data from a MySQL database](https://www.alooma.com/integrations/postgresql/redshift) and load it into your Redshift cluster.

Answer (score 2):

I have done similar task before, but my system was in GCP.

What I did there was to write the data queried out into `AVRO` files, which can be easily (and very efficiently) be ingested into BigQuery.

So there is one task in the dag to query out the data and write to an `AVRO` file in Cloud Storage (S3 equivalent). And one task after that to call BigQuery operator to ingest the `AVRO` file.

You can probably do similar with `csv` file in S3 bucket, and then RedShift `COPY` command from the `csv` file in S3. I believe RedShift `COPY` from file in S3 is the fastest way to ingest data into RedShift.

These tasks are implemented as PythonOperators in Airflow.

Answer (score -4):

You can pass information between tasks using XCom. You can read up on it in the documentation and there is also an example in the set of sample DAGs installed with Airflow by default.

Comment: XCom is intended for "nuanced forms of control and shared state" (quoting the doc). I believe it is not suited to pass the data around as  "users should make sure to use objects of appropriate size". I have modified my question to make it clearer. Thank you Dmitri.